# How do I export these Active Directory User Properties to CSV?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to export these user properties to an Excel CSV. When I run the command without the `Export-CSV` option, it works just fine in Powershell itself. But as soon as that is added to the mix, I get results in a CSV file that start with this (Which shouldn't be there at all):

`#TYPE Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData`

Here is the code, does anyone know what's going on?

```
Get-Content -Path C:\Test\Employee.csv |
Get-ADUser -properties SamAccountName,extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute10,distinguishedName |
FT SamAccountName,extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute10,distinguishedName | Export-CSV -path "C:\Test\test.csv"
```

Comment: Replace `FT` with `select`, and add `-NoTypeInformation` when calling `Export-Csv`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you so much, that was extremely simple!

Not sure how to mark that as the answer, I am extremely new to StackOverflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! No worries, you can't mark a comment "accepted". I've closed your question with reference to another answer that addresses the biggest part of your question (how to not get weird results when using `Format-*` cmdlets with `Export-Csv`) - nothing more for you to do here, but good luck on your PowerShell journey! :-)